Add custom fields into access token cognito
I'm using AWS Cognito to handle the auth part of our app
and I need to add custom fields to the access token returned from Cognito ; like currently user logged organization, if he's impersonating, roles (stored on the app side)...
Recently, AWS did an update where we can add "custom" claims into access token, but theses claims can only be stored from Cognito user pool (custom:parameter...)
Is it possible from the PHP SDK (or something else) to add custom claims?
If not, is it a good practise to keep the refresh token to handle session, but generate a "self" access token not "linked" to the aws refresh token
Thanks
